# Correct way to call animation through and IF statement (A-Frame animation mixer)?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, aframe

I am currently working with the animation mixer in A-Frame and am attempting to make a condition occur when a specific animation is playing (e.g. Animation 'B' out of A, B, C).

I'm unfamiliar with Javascript but I've made several attempts:

```
 if(character.getAttribute == character.getAttribute("animation-mixer", {clip: "B"}){
 //  Insert action here 
 }

 if(character == character.setAttribute("animation-mixer", {clip: "B"})){
 //  Insert action here
 };

 if(character.getAttribute("animation-mixer") == {clip: "B"}){
 //  Insert action here
 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve component data You should just use [getAttribute(componentName)](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/entity.html#getattribute-componentname):

```
// grabbing the component data object
character.getAttribute("animation-mixer")

// same + accessing the clip property
character.getAttribute("animation-mixer").clip

// checking if the property equals "B"
if (character.getAttribute("animation-mixer").clip === "B") {
   console.log("Its B!")
}
```

---

[setAttribute()](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/entity.html#setattribute-componentname-value-propertyvalue-clobber) will change the animation:

```
setAttribute("animation-mixer", "clip", "A")
// or character.setAttribute("animation-mixer", {clip: "B"})
character.getAttribute("animation-mixer").clip // A
```